# Jasmine and position of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I want to test if something happens when an element passes the middle of the window. I just do not seem to get it. This is my source file:

```
        checkIfWorkInMiddle: function(element) {
        var middelOfScreen = this.getMiddleOfScreen();
        var posAboveBottom = this.getPosAboveBottom(element);
        if (posBottomAboveBottom > middelOfScreen) {
            return true;
        }
```

The position of the element depends on the scroll position. When I do my test the element is always below the middleofscreen. How can I changes this in my test? My spec file is as follows:

```
describe("Get Middle of screen" , function() {
it('returns true if above the middle of screen' , function() {
    var fakeElement = Object.create( blocks );
    var x = fakeElement.checkIfWorkInMiddle(element);

    expect(x).toBeTruthy();
});
```

});

So this always returns false in the test. What can I do in my test to force posBottomAboveBottom to be a different value. So actually fake a scroll event? I hope my problem is clear?

Comment: Some markup and CSS would be nice to actually see where the element is on the page. Maybe you could create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using

```
 window.scrollTo(x,y);
```

Then pass in the middle or below middle values like y = 500. This will position the window so Jasmine can then run the test so.

```
it("check is .... ", function(){
    window.scroll(0,400);
    var fakeElement = Object.create( blocks );
     var x = fakeElement.checkIfWorkInMiddle(element);

     expect(x).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I found the solution however. Which was quite obvious. An even simpler example. Two methods (x1 and y1) of an object. One methods uses the other to store its return value in a variable. You could imagine that y1 presents the top of an element.

```
x1 : function() {
        var p = this.y1();
        if (p > 3) {
            return 'bigger';
        } else {
            return 'smaller'
        }
    },
y1: function() {
        return 1;
    }
```

I want to influence the position of the element and thus in this simplified example the return value of y1 in my test . I do this as follows:

```
describe("See if Called" , function() {
   it('check if returns the valid value' , function() {
    var fakeElement = Object.create( blocks );
    spyOn(fakeElement, 'y1').andCallFake(function() {
        return 4;
    });
   var x = fakeElement.x1();
   expect(x).toEqual("bigger");
   });
});
```

and this passes. Hope this might still help someone..